# Convert a class component into a function component

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to convert this class component into a function component. I tried a lot and failed. Is there a solution to the problem?

```
componentDidMount(){
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    getById( parseInt(id) )
    .then(product => {
    this.setState({
      product,
      loading: false
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can add some more details to your question and which problems you are struggling with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet is equal `componentDidMount` in class component:

```
// ...
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
const [product, setProduct] = React.useState(void 0);

React.useEffect(() => {
  // Did mount, put your code here
  setLoading(true)
 
  // Fetch done
  .then(product => {
    setLoading(false)
    setProduct(product)
  })

}, []);
```

Comment: How do I change this to work with me:                    
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;

    getById( parseInt(id) )
    .then(product => {

      this.setState({
          product,
          loading: false
      });

    })

Comment: I dropped a draft idea for you

Comment: How do I change this. Props

Comment: The `props` is the argument of your functional component: `const YourComponent = (props) => { //... }`